# index.php is downloading instead of displaying

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php

I have set a local website from following [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts),

I have followed everything as it is but when I access my site via Mozilla Browser, *it asks me where to download* and save *instead of displaying the `index.php`*

Any solution?

Comment: Have you installed both **Apache** & **php**?? Remember, `php` doesn't come packed with apache.. by looking at your question, it seems you don't have `php installed. Can you kindly add more in-detail as to what you've done so far. This will help me to assist you better. :)

Comment: Ohhh man! I actually installed OpenStack and it installed Apache and mySQL but not PHP.

I now installed and it is working.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I could help you! let me post it as an answer for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the look of the issue, it seems you've not installed **PHP** as it denies to view page, and downloads instead.

As I've commented, **Apache** doesn't come packed with **PHP** as it is a separate package. Installing `php` package should simply fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

apache2 doesn't come with php preinstalled.
And then restart apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: A more complete command is `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5`. Installing only the `php5` package is not enough, you also need to install the apache php module.

Comment: Oh, did not know that :D