# How to get APR or access httpd.conf, or get PHP to run?

Tags: apache2, php

When I try to run a PHP file with a browser, it tries to save the file rather than run it.  I read that this may have something to do with my httpd.conf file, and trying to follow what I read here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/where-is-my-httpd-conf-file-located-apache#12202042

when I run

```
httpd -V
```

I get that it doesn't recognize the command.  When I run

```
ps -ef | grep apache2
```

I get most file locations being `/usr/local/apache2 -k start` but I can't navigate to that location--it says that's not a directory.

So 1) is this what I should be doing? 2) If so, how do I get to my httpd.conf file, and 3) when there, what should I do to it (because the instructions I found seemed targeted to a server and I'm just doing this on my laptop so that I can run small scripts for web design)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [index.php is downloading instead of displaying](http://askubuntu.com/questions/447675/index-php-is-downloading-instead-of-displaying)

Comment: `httpd`? `/usr/local/apache2`? Is this Ubuntu? If so, why aren't you using the packages?

Comment: @muru I don't know what the packages are.  I don't really understand what I'm doing, I'm just taking my best guess about what I ought to do based on the google results I've found.    If there's another way to make the browser render rather than save, I'm all ears.

Comment: Start with https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/web-servers.html then